# Sintácticamente, ¿qué es "algo del todo inimaginable en aquella ciudad"?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Cómo puedo identificar la parte en negrita desde el punto de vista sintáctico?

> Los transeúntes que se cruzaban con él miraban siempre al frente y
>   nadie hacía el menor intento por encarar su rostro, **algo del todo
>   inimaginable en aquella ciudad**.

Yo diría que es una oración simple, una oración aclaratoria (si existe algo así).

Comment: Aurora, recuerda que debes poner el trabajo que intentaste al analizar la afirmación. Es importante para poder entregar diferentes puntos de vista.

Comment: sí, perdonad... bueno, yo diría que es una oración simple, una oración aclaratoria (si existe algo así)...

Comment: Aurora: has formulado muchas preguntas recientemente y no has dado respuesta a los comentarios que allí se han formulado. Antes de seguir adelante con nuevas dudas, es bueno que valores si has entendido bien lo que ya formulaste. De esta forma podrás aprender de una forma más consistente, sin tener que recurrir a formular tantas preguntas parecidas. Intenta hacerlo, así como editar esta pregunta para esclarecerla, y seguro que muchos de por aquí estaremos encantados de ayudarte.

Comment: Bueno, chicos, en primer lugar os agradezco mucho x vuesta ayuda y vuestros consejos, pero en realidad me desespero viendo que seguís poniendo mis preguntas on hold. ¿qué es lo que no queda claro en mi pregunta? Solo quería saber que oración es el fragmento en negrita. No sabía la respuesta y por eso lo pregunté aquí (y no he puesto mi respuesta por que me parecía ridicula). En lo que se refiere a otras preguntas: x ej. no entendí bien el comentario de Ustanak y estaba esperando q alguien diera una respuesta. Lo siento si no sigo las reglas del site y lo siento si os causo algún inconveniente

Comment: Tu sugerencia no va mal encaminada. Ten en cuenta que el fragmento resaltado no puede ser una oración porque no tiene un verbo conjugado. Se trata de un sintagma nominal con función de **aposición explicativa**. El nombre al que complementa la aposición no es fácilmente identificable. Sería "el hecho de que los transeúntes que se cruzaban con él miraran..." Si solo tienes que identificar el fragmento resaltado, *aposición explicativa* sería suficiente. Si tienes que analizar la oración completa, no sabría a qué nivel colocarlo.

Comment: @Yay: sí sí esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba :) muchísimas gracias, eres un sol

Comment: @Aurora para nada causas inconveniente. Dado que parece que sí fue lo suficientemente entendible, gracias también a la edición de DGaleano, la reabro. Sería bueno que leyeras [ask] para mejorar la experiencia en este sitio y formular las siguientes preguntas utilizando títulos más específicos y mostrando cuál fue tu investigación previa. Y no dudes en utilizar `@usuario` para contactar con quien sea si tienes dudas.

Comment: @Yay ya que sí fue clara la pregunta para ti, la reabrimos para que puedas contestarla con una respuesta en lugar de en los comentarios. ¿Te parece? ¡Gracias por tus aportaciones!

Comment: @fedorqui Me parece estupendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que el fragmento resaltado no puede ser una oración porque no contiene un verbo conjugado. Se trata de un sintagma nominal con función de **aposición explicativa**. El nombre al que complementa la aposición (*El hecho de que los transeúntes que se cruzaban con él miraran siempre al frente y que nadie hiciera el menor intento por encarar su rostro*) no es fácilmente identificable en términos sintácticos. De hecho, la Nueva gramática comenta brevemente el problema de la aposición sin referente nominal claro a la hora de analizar la sintaxis de una oración en la sección [12.15e](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QMlzPSbWzERkTNTU):

> **12.15e** La relación atributiva que se establece en las aposiciones explicativas puede ser algo más compleja, sobre todo cuando el elemento nominal al que se atribuye cierta propiedad no constituye un segmento sintáctico de la oración. Así, el grupo nominal que encabeza el sustantivo *estilo* en el texto que sigue se predica de *cubismo*, pero ese sustantivo no aparece (en esa forma) en el fragmento que lo precede: *Jaime Colson fue un cubista auténtico, estilo desde el cual hizo prevalecer el reino de la técnica* (Artes 04/2003). De forma análoga, este otro texto contiene un grupo nominal apositivo encabezado por el sustantivo *tarea*: *Desempeñó la presidencia de la Empresa Carbonífera Schwager, tarea sumamente difícil* (CREA oral, Chile). Sin embargo, dicho grupo nominal no se predica de *presidencia*, sino de una noción proposicional que no se presenta aquí en forma nominal u oracional: la acción de desempeñar la presidencia de cierta empresa. Sobre aposiciones explicativas como las encabezadas por *cosa que...* y otras semejantes, véase el §44.3ñ.

El apartado [§44.3ñ](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wMXfFjyDXQPvkJfI) al que nos remite el fragmento anterior no aporta mucha más información, aparte de comentar que las proposiciones encabezados por *el que* o *el cual* se aproximan más a relativas libres o semilibres que a explicativas.

En resumen, parece que has dado con una construcción no del todo clara desde el punto de vista sintáctico. La Nueva gramática se queda en **aposición explicativa**, y la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposici%C3%B3n#Aposici.C3.B3n_del_sustantivo_a_la_frase) la describe como un caso de **aposición a la frase**.

Comment: Gracias por hacer el análisis sintáctico un poco más fácil : )